# Selecting derived class based on function parameter

Tags: c++

I have these classes:

```
class Base
{
  private:
    string name;
  public:
    void setName(string n);
    string getName();
    void toString();
}
```

and two classes derived from this:

```
class DerivedA : public Base
{
  private:
    int width;
  public:
    void setWidth(int w);
    int getWidth();

}
```

and

```
class DerivedB : public Base
{
  private:
    int height;
  public:
    void setHeight(int h);
    int getHeight();
}
```

Now to my question. My main looks like this:

```
int main()
{        
  Base* b;    
  string line;
  ... file loading ...

  while(...)
  {
    s = cin.getline(file,10);        
    if(s == "w")
    {
      b = new DerivedA();        
    }
    else if(s == "h")
    {
      b = new DerivedB();
    }
    while(...)
    {
      b->toString();
    }
  }

return 0;
}
```

This always terminates my app. I found out that the `b->toString();` part might be the source of the problem, because of different scopes. But anyway, is there a way how can I do this? (I left out boring and unrelated parts of code.)

Comment: Are you sure that one of those `if` statements is executing? If none of them execute, `b` is left uninitialized, which might be your problem.

Comment: Does that even compile?!

Comment: You're also leaking memory since you never delete b, if this runs for a while you'll eventually get an out of memory exception.

Comment: Your base class needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: You also should mark `toString` virtual if you're planning on overriding it.

Comment: if you go Base* b = NULL;   and then check that b != NULL before you use b in the while loop,   what happens?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that one of these `if` statements is executing everytime. I know about memory issue, right now it's kinda irrelevant but thanks for pointing it out. Setting `Base* b` to `NULL` is not helping but thanks.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure"?  Not good enough :) I would add some debug/println/cout(s) to find out what's happening.  Or, just run in the debugger.

Comment: I export that file from my webserver, and I just checked that code, it's always either `h` or `w`.

Comment: Can you post the actual failing code?

Comment: First, fix the things you know you should fix before worrying about anything else. Memory leaks are never irrelevant. Also, you want to have a default `Else` to catch what you need. Never DEPEND on input.

Comment: @HlavacekMichal Have you debugged you application to be 100% sure that it executes if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base` should have a virtual destructor and every function you intend to override should be declared `virtual`.  Additionally, your `main` function needs some modifications:

```
int main()
{        
    Base* b = nullptr; // initialize your pointer    
    string line;
    // ... file loading ...

    while(std::getline(file, line)) // this should be your while loop for your file parsing
    {
        //s = cin.getline(file,10); // why???  you appear to be trying to pass your ifstream object into cin's istream::getline method ... this won't even compile!

        // I'm assuming s is a std::string, and you pull it out of the line variable at some point ...
        if(s == "w")
        {
           if (b != nullptr) // properly free your memory
           {
               delete b;
               b = nullptr;
           }
           b = new DerivedA();        
        }
        else if(s == "h")
        {
           if (b != nullptr) // properly free your memory
           {
               delete b;
               b = nullptr;
           }
            b = new DerivedB();
        }

        while(...)
        {
            if (b != nullptr) // make sure b is valid!
            {
                b->toString();
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> This always terminates my app. I found out that the b->toString();
>   part might be the source of the problem, because of different scopes.
>   But anyway, is there a way how can I do this?

To start off with, what you have posted will (likely) not even compile.  `cin.getline` will attempt to read from standard input.  Your comment indicates you are loading a file, so (assuming that `file` is an `std::ifstream` instance, `cin.getline(file, 10)` is attempting to call a function `std::istream::getline(std::istream&, int)`, which does not exist.  `std::getline` does what it appears you want to do here.  Additionally, even if you are attempting to read from standard input, it should be `std::getline(std::cin, s)`, not `cin.getline(file, 10)`.

Moving on, the next area is your memory leaks.  Those are easy enough to fix by 1) initializing `b` when it is declared, and 2) properly `delete`ing it before you leak memory.  The null checks are not totally necessary (with an initialized `b`), since `delete` will check for `NULL` anyway, but I wrote them in there to illustrate a point:  you should be managing your memory properly!

Next up, your if-else if-condition has the potential to not do anything (that is, `b` would be uninitialized at worse, or `NULL` at best).  If you don't want to do anything for non-"s"/"h" inputs, that is fine, but then you **must** do the following item (which you should do anyway).

Finally, the issue that is likely causing your crash is not checking if `b` is valid before attempting to use it:  `b->toString();`.  If `b` is invalid or null, you are invoking undefined behavior.  Your program may crash, call your grandmother, or order a pizza for the President ... all would be valid options, and non of them are what you really intended to do.

Comment: I don't think this deserves to be an "answer"

Comment: @khajvah Care to elaborate?

Comment: This isn't answer to his question. You have provided some useful information but this is not an answer "Why it isn't working?" or "HOw can I do this?". This will compile and run but most likely it won't work like OP expects, since you only prevented it from failing. To be fair, it is impossible to answer by the information OP provided but still...

Comment: The answer to his question is in the changes:  primarily, the null-check before he tries to call `b->toString()` (which will likely cause his program to crash when he calls it with a null or uninitialized pointer).  And actually, there is one part that will not compile as he has it written (which I mention in the edits).

Comment: This is what I think will happen when OP tests your answer: "YAY, it is running without problems" and then "wait, `b->toString()` isn't being executed, let me go back to SO."

Comment: Ignoring your assumption for a minute.  The first thing he will think is "Yay!  It is **compiling**!"  What he has now (specifically the `cin.getline(ifstream&, int)` line) will not compile.  His question at the moment is not "how do I accomplish this task ...?", but "how do I stop it from crashing?"  Not attempting to use uninitialized (or null) pointers is how he does that.  The followup question (which you are attempting to read his mind to get to) is "why isn't my if-condition executing" ... and that has to do with his file input, but is not necessary to fix his crash.

Comment: I am not talking about `cin.getline` because I never used it and I don't want to read the documentation for now but OP said "terminates my app" which I think means that it compiles and it is runtime error.(I think he would provide compiler errors otherwise) Also, he somehow "found out that the `b->toString();` part might be the source of the problem, because of different scopes.", though I don't quite understand what he means by "different scopes"(my English maybe). Whatever, this is getting nowhere, I hope you are right and this will fix his problems.

Comment: @khajvah See my edit as I went into much more detail.

Comment: @ZacHowland Thanks for your answer, I'll revisit my code and let you know.

Comment: @khajvah I'm glad that you think others can be stupid enough to do such a thing :-) Actually this was my first question since I joined SO a year or so ago. And I don't feel like asking another one for the same problem.

Comment: @HlavacekMichal Excuse me if I offended you in any way. The point is that I thought and think it is a runtime error. To be honest, I think you could add more info. But whatever, Zac has written a complete answer that covers everything and will most likely solve your problem :)

Comment: I fixed my code according to your solution and it's working now, thanks to you and everyone else in this thread. My code was generally in bad shape I suppose.